# Очень медленно выполненяется запрос на счетчик Disqus

Tags: производительность, disqus

Очень долго выполняется запрос на счетчик Disqus. 
Как бороться?

http://take.ms/08XDS

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    var disqus_shortname = '*****';
    (function () {
        var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
        for (var i = 0, url; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (nodes[i].className.indexOf('dsq-postid') != -1) {
                nodes[i].parentNode.setAttribute('data-disqus-identifier', nodes[i].getAttribute('data-dsqidentifier'));
                url = nodes[i].parentNode.href.split('#', 1);
                if (url.length == 1) { url = url[0]; }
                else { url = url[1]; }
                nodes[i].parentNode.href = url + '#disqus_thread';
            }
        }
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.async = true;
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
    }());
    // ]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: Проблема не у вашего сайта, а у Disqus или у пользователя с доступом к Disqus. От меня запрос сейчас выглядит так http://jpegshare.net/6c/e4/6ce442b5677ab12d105d3ebc647158ac.gif.html

Comment: "Переходим с Disqus на комментарии Github" https://habrahabr.ru/post/327424/